# Total spin on a two-particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

How can I know the total spin of a given state quickly? I first encountered this problem when proving the Clebsch-Gordan series.

Consider a two-particle system (to make it easier, let's say identical particles), so the states in the product space are $$|j,j:m_1,m_2\rangle$$ Now we want to prove that the space $$\nu_j\otimes \nu_j=\nu_{2j}\otimes \nu_{2j-1}\otimes...\otimes \nu_0.$$

Now the first step to construct the space is to consider a CSCO like $\{\mathbb{\vec{J}}^2,\mathbb{J}_3\} $ that are defined as $$\mathbb{\vec{J}}^2=(\vec{J}_{(1)}^2+\vec{J}_{(2)}^2)$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$\mathbb{J}_3=J_{(1)3}+J_{(2)3}$$ where the parenthesis subscript means which space they are acting on.

Now the deal is, we start by saying $|j,j:j,j\rangle$ is the ceiling state so that $\mathbb{J}_+$ cancels it. And then start applying $\mathbb{J}_-$ to go through the first subspace $\nu_{2j}$. Then we construct by orthonormality the ceiling vector in $\nu_{2j-1}$ as $$1/\sqrt{2} (|j,j:j-1,j\rangle - |j,j:j,j-1\rangle).$$
I can get here with no problems.

> **The question is** : How do we know that the total spin of these states is right? Meaning, how can we quickly compute the eigenvalues of $\mathbb{\vec{J}}^2$?

Comment: Good books detail "how [you] know". But you want "quick" because their proofs are fussy?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I got an expression for the total spin inn terms of J+, J- and J3, but when doing the proof my teacher didn't even check for the total spin to be right. That's why I was wondering if there is a quick way to calculate it from a given state

Comment: Merzbacher, Messiah, Dirac, Sakurai's texts all detail the [triangle construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space).

Comment: Of course you can just look up CG coefficients and compare with your expressions.  On the other hand $\hat J_\pm$ cannot change Total $J$ since they commute with total $J^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the top state $\vert j,j\rangle$, then the action of $\hat J_-$ *cannot* change $j$ so you are guaranteed that $\hat J_-^p\vert j,j\rangle$ is proportional to $\vert j,j-p\rangle$, i.e. you are guaranteed that the state will have the same $j$ value as the top state.  This follows because *by definition* the ladder operators change *only* the projection but do not change the angular momentum value of state.  Alternatively, $[\hat J_\pm,\hat J^2]=0$.

The technical difficulty is in efficiently evaluating the action of $\hat J_-^p$ 
on $\vert j,j\rangle$.  One can expand
\begin{align}
\hat J_-^p&=\left(\hat J_{(1)-}+ \hat J_{(2)-}\right)^p\, ,\\
&= \sum_q {p \choose{q}} \left(\hat J_{(1)-}\right)^q \left(\hat J_{(2)-}\right)^{p-q} \tag{1}
\end{align}
since the lowering operators acting on different states commute, but the action of this on a complicated state $\vert j,j\rangle$ is non-trivial, and you have to normalize $\hat J_-^p\vert j,j\rangle$.  This strategy basically amounts to computing CG coefficients by hand, so in this sense one is redoing work already available.

One “quick” way to do this if you are given a *normalized state* 
\begin{align}
\vert\psi\rangle = \sum_{mm’} C_{mm’} \vert \ell m\rangle \vert \ell’ m’\rangle 
\tag{2}
\end{align}
is to verify that each $C_{mm’}$ actually the CG coefficient for a specific $j$.  This can be painful since, for instance (assuming one can immediately identify an overall phase difference with the CG table), the combination 
\begin{align}
\vert\psi\rangle&= a \vert j_1,m\rangle + b\vert j_2,m‘\rangle
\end{align}
will be an eigenstate of $J^2$ when $j_1=j_2$ but not of $\hat J_z$ if $m’\ne m$, whereas it will not be an eigenstate of $J^2$ when $j_1\ne j_2$.  In other words, because the CG assume eigenstates of $\hat J_z$, Eq.(2) can be useful in some cases where the CGs can be verified easily but is not so useful when $\vert\psi\rangle$ is not an eigenstate of $\hat J_z$.

The most general way is to write explicitly the operator $J^2$ in terms of $\hat J_{(1),i}$ and $\hat J_{(2),k}$ and check by hand.